# Generate cryptographically secure random numbers in php

Tags: php, security, random

PHP's `rand()` function doesn't give good random numbers. So I started to use `mt_rand()` which is said to give better results. But how good are these results? Are there any methods to improve them again?

My idea:

```
function rand_best($min, $max) {
    $generated = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++) {
        $generated[] = mt_rand($min, $max);
    }
    shuffle($generated);
    $position = mt_rand(0, 99);
    return $generated[$position];
}
```

This should give you "perfect" random numbers, shouldn't it?

Comment: This is a duplicate of one of my questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611/better-random-generating-php

Comment: Newest version of php has a [cryptographically secure PRNG](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31443898/1090562).

Comment: If anybody is reading this, skip the accepted answer because [this answer is the correct one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31443898/2224584). If you're stuck on PHP 5, check out [random_compat](https://github.com/paragonie/random_compat).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

[Pseudorandom number generators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator) (PRNG) are very complex beast.

There are no real "perfect" random number generators -- in fact the best that can be done from mathematical functions are pseudorandom -- they seem random enough for most intents and purposes.

In fact, performing any additional actions from a number returned by a PRNG doesn't really increase its randomness, and in fact, the number can become less random.

So, my best advice is, don't mess around with values returned from a PRNG. Use a PRNG that is good enough for the intended use, and if it isn't, then find a PRNG that can produce better results, if necessary.

And frankly, it appears that the [`mt_rand`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php) function uses the [Mersenne twister](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister), which is a pretty good PRNG as it is, so it's probably going to be good enough for most casual use.

However, **Mersenne Twister is not designed to be used in any security contexts**. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31443898) for a solution to use when you need randomness to ensure security.

**Edit**

There was a question in the comments why performing operations on a random number can make it less random. For example, some PRNGs can return more consistent, less random numbers in different parts of the bits -- the high-end can be more random than the low-end.

Therefore, in operations where the high-end is discarded, and the low end is returned, the value can become less random than the original value returned from the PRNG.

I can't find a good explanation at the moment, but I based that from the Java documentation for the [`Random.nextInt(int)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt(int)) method, which is designed to create a fairly random value in a specified range. That method takes into account the difference in randomness of the parts of the value, so it can return a better random number compared to more naive implementations such as `rand() % range`.

Comment: How can it become 'less random'?

Comment: karim: Since all PRNGs are based on calculations which just generate apparently random numbers there are certain drawbacks. In principle generating "random" numbers goes against everything a computer can do, since computers are—by design—deterministic machines. Depending on which calculations are performed on the numbers to generate random bits there are some that exhibit statistically good randomness and some that do not. That depends on your generator, though. LCGs have weak low bits, other types have weak high bits, others even don't exhibit any weakness. It is a very complex topic.

Comment: coobird: Java's Random.nextInt(int) does _not_ cater for weaker bits. What it does is eliminating bias due to the modulus operation which would prefer smaller values. It took me two days to understand why it works but it does it very elegantly. But 600 chars is too short for this. The part that discards low-order bits (because of less randomness) is done in Random.next(int): return (int)(seed >>> (48 - bits)). As you can see, at most 32 of the 48 bits of the LCG are returned there which does a good job eliminating the "weak" low-order bits.

Comment: Thank you very much. So I'll just use mt_rand(). I thought there are some possibilities to improve the randomness but apparently there aren't.

Comment: marco: If in doubt, just don't. Meddling with pseudo-random numbers needs great care to not ruin the result. If you know nothing about what you are doing you most likely make things worse.

Answer (score 30):

**Quick answer:**

In a new [PHP7](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/easy_userland_csprng) there is a finally a support for a [cryptographically secure pseudo-random integers.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.random-int.php)

```
int random_int ( int $min , int $max )
```

There is also a [polyfill for PHP5x](https://github.com/paragonie/random_compat).

**Longer answer**

---

There is no perfect random number generator, and computers use [pseudorandom number generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator) to create sequences that looks random. The sequences look random (and pass some [randomness tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randomness_tests)) but because there is some algorithm to generate it, you can repeat algorithm with absolutely the same states and get the same result.

The same advice as with [cryptography](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2011/04/schneiers_law.html) "do not invent your own cypher" can be translated to random number generators and mean that you can not just get a lot of random number generators combined together and get expect to get a better generator.

---

One of the subsets of random number generators is [cryptographically secure random number generators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator):

> The requirements of an ordinary PRNG are also satisfied by a
>   cryptographically secure PRNG, but the reverse is not true. CSPRNG
>   requirements fall into two groups: first, that they pass statistical
>   randomness tests; and secondly, that they hold up well under serious
>   attack, even when part of their initial or running state becomes
>   available to an attacker

So this is pretty close to your definition of "*perfect*". One more time under no condition (except of learning how to do cryptography) you should try to implement one of that algorithms and use it in your system.

---

But luckily [PHP7](http://php.net/manual/en/function.random-int.php) has it implemented,

```
int random_int ( int $min , int $max )
```

> Generates cryptographic random integers that are suitable for use
>   where unbiased results are critical (i.e. shuffling a Poker deck).

The sources of random are as follows:

- On Windows CryptGenRandom() is used exclusively
- arc4random_buf() is used if it is available (generally BSD specific)
- /dev/arandom is used where available
- The `getrandom(2)` syscall (on newer Linux kernels)
- /dev/urandom is used where none of the above is available

This makes all the previous answers obsolete (and some deprecated).

Comment: openssl_random_pseudo_bytes has been around since 2009/5.3.0.. just wrap it in something that checks for the strong_crypto, eg `function f($len){$ret=openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($len,$strong);if(!$strong){throw new \RuntimeException('$crypto_strong failed!');}return $ret;}`

Answer (score 17):

I'm not sure that what you've done "improves" the randomness.  From what I can understand you generate 100 random numbers and then randomly pick one of them.

From what I can remember from my probability course, this probably doesn't increase the randomness, as if there is an underlying bias in the generator function (mt_rand()), then it will still be reflected somehow in the output.

Comment: You've understood it correctly. Thanks for your answer. Now I know that I can't improve the randomness with further calculations.

Comment: What if you had two different RNG algorithms? Have you improved things then?

Answer (score 14):

In what way is mt_rand() "bad"?

For example: If it favors a certain number. Lets say mt_rand(1, 10) favours low numbers in the range, ie "1" and "2" occurs on average more than 10% each. Then your "improvement" would still suffer from the same problem.

Selecting a random number out of a faulty sequence will still be faulty.

Comment: Yep, this is exactly what I was thinking.

Comment: +1 just for "Selecting a random number out of a faulty sequence will still be faulty.".

Answer (score 12):

```
<?php
  function random_number(){
      return 4; // return generated number
                // guaranteed to be random
  }
  ?>
```

All joking aside, you're getting into a philosophical question of what is "random" or what is "best".  Ideally you'd want your random numbers to have few patterns in them over the course of your procedure.  Generally system time is used as the seed, but I've also used the previous random number as the seed, the previous random numberth ago as the seed.  The problem is, with a powerful enough computer and full knowledge of the hardware running, and generator function, you would be able to predict the entire set of numbers generated.  Thus if you had a powerful enough computer (some people put God into this category) that knew all possible variables and functions of the universe you would then be able to predict every event that happened or will happen.  Most random number generators are fine on their own but if you know someone who can see the patterns, more likely they are like the guy in Beautiful Mind and you should get them checked into a clinic.

[By popular demand](http://xkcd.com/221/) :D

Comment: Not sure people who don't read xkcd would get the joke.  Probably would've been better linking it.

Comment: instead I'll just insert the image

Comment: At first, I didn't understand the joke. But after seeing the comic on the linked page, I did, of course. :D

Answer (score 5):

I wrote a cronjob that gets 1000 numbers from random.org periodically (say, once an hour) and added them into a PHP array. Whenever I want random numbers in my script, I use mt_rand(0,1000) to call a number from that. A few extra microseconds of overhead, but I get truly random numbers based on natural atmospheric noise.

Comment: That introduces the possibility of re-using the same numbers within the array before it is refreshed, which is a *much* smaller set of possible values than the full range of 32-bit integers even if the thousand numbers come from the larger range. A better method would be to treat the array as a queue; adding new values as needed, always using the first item and discarding it afterwards.

Comment: I generated random numbers using the criteria "num=10000&min=1&max=1000000" on random.org and got 50 duplicate values. So its seems its not truly random in nature.

Answer (score 2):

It all depends what for you need that random number :)
For me [ShuffleBag](http://kaioa.com/node/53) is the best one :)

Answer (score 2):

Edit: My comment is no longer valid. Please see the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31443898/109561

---

I'm guessing you're worried about the distribution of mt_rand(). I have tested it and it is very level and both bounds are inclusive.

I added my test to the comments of the documentation for mt_rand() on the php manual, but it was removed by a silly moderator due to politics that are too long winded to go into here.

Comment: I should also note that for true random numbers (if there is such a thing) they will become more evenly distributed as the number of iterations approaches infinity. While this is also true with mt_rand(), from my tests it seems on average to be a lot quicker at gaining more even distribution.

Comment: That all depends on which distribution the random numbers follow. It it's a uniform distribution, then yes. But there are specialized PRNGs that generate random numbers in other distributions as well (normal, exponential, ...) which saves you the effort of altering the distribution (as for some distributions there are no easy/good/efficient ways). When looked upon from only one dimension, rand() and mt_rand() should look fairly the same in terms of "randomness". It's starting from 3 dimensions upward where things get fun with LCGs :-)

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as a "perfect" random number.  No matter what subjective definition of "perfect" you have.  You can only achieve pseudo-random.

I was simply trying to point you in the right direction.  You asked a question about perfect random numbers, even if perfect was in quotes.  And yes, you can improve randomness.  You can even implement heuristic or "natural" algorithms, such ideas like "atmospheric noise" -- but still, you're not perfect, not by any means.

Comment: But even if there are only pseudo-random numbers, you can improve the randomness, can't you?

Comment: Randomness is simply the inverse of our ability to predict output... so a perfect random binary digit is only 50% 'random'.  To create 'true' random numbers requires eliminating predictable patterns between numbers, and the best way to do this is by using processes that we humans really don't understand very well; like radioactive decay and atmospheric noise.  These sources are available online, look up HotBits and Random.org for those sources respectively.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like PHP's built in `rand()`, you probably shouldn't use their built-in `shuffle()` either, since it seems to be built on their `rand()`.

I am halfway sure the "industry standard" shuffle now is the [Fisher-Yates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher-Yates_shuffle) shuffle.

Answer (score 1):

use /dev/ramdom (linux device true random number generator) to seed mt_rand

```
<?
$rnd_dev=mcrypt_create_iv(4, MCRYPT_DEV_RANDOM); //need "apt-get install php5-mcrypt"
$seed=ord(substr($rnd_dev, 0, 1))<<24 |
      ord(substr($rnd_dev, 1, 1))<<16 |
      ord(substr($rnd_dev, 2, 1))<<8 |
      ord(substr($rnd_dev, 3, 1));
mt_srand($seed);
echo mt_rand();
?>
```

Comment: Without an external source of noise, a computer cannot have a 'true random number generator', and if it did, why use it to seed a less random source?  If you already had 'true' random numbers, why not just use them?

Answer (score 0):

I made a PHP class for generating random numbers and strings [PHPRandomValue](https://github.com/ejfrancis/PHPRandomValue)

It uses "mcrypt_create_iv(4, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM)"  to generate random numbers and values. I made it while working on a crypto project because I needed a safe random value generator. Here's an example usage

```
$randomValue = new RandomValue;

$randomValue->randomNumber(): = -3880998

$randomValue->randomNumberBetween(1,10): = 2

$randomValue->randomTextString(): = CfCkKDHRgUULdGWcSqP4

$randomValue->randomTextString(10):  = LorPIxaeEY

$randomValue->randomKey(): = C7al8tX9.gqYLf2ImVt/!$NOY79T5sNCT/6Q.$!.6Gf/Q5zpa3

$randomValue->randomKey(10):  = RDV.dc6Ai/
```

Answer (score -1):

It is not possible to generate true random numbers, the best you can hope for is pseudo-random which is what rand() provides, your function is no closer to random then rand(). Take a look at this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generator

Comment: You mean mt_rand(), the rand() function in php has been shown to be flawed.

Comment: mt_rand() and rand() are no more flawed then any other psuedo-RNG, as far as I know.

Comment: The difference lies in the algorithm and provable statistical properties of the random numbers. And rand() does *not* suffice for many applications. Furthermore, the Mersenne Twister is fast enough and generates much higher-quality numbers so for people without deep knowledge of the field you can safely suggest MT19937 instead of the built-in rand().

Comment: Just a minor addition, here; a visual guide to some of the problems with rand(): [link](http://cod.ifies.com/2008/05/php-rand01-on-windows-openssl-rand-on.html)

Answer (score -1):

Tru Random numbers

```
<?php
for ($i = -1; $i <= 4; $i++) {
    $bytes = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($i, $cstrong);
    $hex   = bin2hex($bytes);

    echo "Lengths: Bytes: $i and Hex: " . strlen($hex) . PHP_EOL;
    var_dump($hex);
    var_dump($cstrong);
    echo PHP_EOL;
}
?>
```

and also crypto secure ;)

Answer (score -2):

Although the answer was accepted years ago, I'll re-reopen it.

Since all this randomness depends on the system time, let's mess with the system time too! The amount of time an operation takes on the computer is actually rather variable (especially if other stuff is happening on that server), so if we take advantage of that with microtime... (couldn't find any portable nanotime commands)

```
$a='';
for (int $i=0; $i<9001; $i++)
{
    usleep(mt_rand(1000,10000));//Also eliminates timing attacks... possibly?
    $a=hash('SHA512',$a.uniqid(mt_rand().microtime(),true));
}
echo $a;
```

Nominally this has 207023 bits of entropy, since you're adding another 23 bits every iteration, but there's a lot of interdependencies, so it's probably a few orders of magnitude less. Still pretty good.

Do you know of any operations on PHP that take a really random amount of time? Like... HTTP-requesting some website (other than RANDOM.org) and measuring the time it takes?

Answer (score -3):

Using random.org, you can use this:

```
function getToken($length, $min, $max){
    $r = explode('
',file_get_contents('http://www.random.org/integers/num='.$length.'&min='.$min.'&max='.$max.'&col=1&base=10&format=plain'));

    $string = '';
    foreach ( $r as $char ) $string.=$char;
    return $string;
}
```

this should give real random numbers

Comment: I generated random numbers using the criteria "num=10000&min=1&max=1000000" on random.org and got 50 duplicate values. So its seems its not truly random in nature.