# Never Generate Random Number Again

Tags: php, random, hyperlink

I am looking for a random number generating PHP Solution which did not generate same number again.. is there any solution then please let me know..

I need this solution for one of my Project which generate uniqu key for URL and i don't want to check Generated number is existed or not from the data..

Thanks..

--------- EDIT ----------

I am using this random number generating method is its help full?

```
function randomString($length = 10, $chars = '1234567890') {

// Alpha lowercase
if ($chars == 'alphalower') {
    $chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
}

// Numeric
if ($chars == 'numeric') {
    $chars = '1234567890';
}

// Alpha Numeric
if ($chars == 'alphanumeric') {
    $chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890';
}

// Hex
if ($chars == 'hex') {
    $chars = 'ABCDEF1234567890';
}

$charLength = strlen($chars)-1;

for($i = 0 ; $i < $length ; $i++)
    {
        $randomString .= $chars[mt_rand(0,$charLength)];
    }

return $randomString;
}
```

Comment: what range of numbers you're looking for?

Comment: [GUID on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier): "This number is so large that the probability of the same number being generated randomly twice is negligible."

Comment: If its unable to generate the same number again then its not a random number generator its simple a unique counter/globally unique number generator. Just to be clear you do not want a random number generator.

Comment: @Ramhound your are right but i need a random solution.. just like add time/date etc and generate number?

Comment: Any random number generator that satisfies these constraints would become less and less random as time goes by. (A *very* poor feature)

Comment: if i use counter but still i need to check random number form data..

Comment: "is its help full?" - no. You're just adding more code around a flawed algorithm

Comment: GUID is perhaps the most wrong (but still pertinent) answer to this question that I can think of.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the php function `uniqid()`:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php

Comment: Sometimes I fear that trying to systematically generate guids to prevent the possibility of collision actually _increases_ the chance of collision...

Comment: @Robert: do you have any reason for believing that?

Comment: its enough for me.. i add uniqid() with my random number so now its much safer then before.. maybe its chance of duplicate in 2000000000 entry..

Comment: "maybe its chance of duplicate in 2000000000 entry" do not vomit random numbers just because you feel to.

Comment: its not a big problem if 2-20 random are same.. but i don't want ten of thousand same random number..

Comment: @recursive Yes. V1 guids are an example of exactly that.

Answer (score 2):

It's impossible to generate a random number which is unique - if the generator is dependent on state, then the output is by definition not random.

It is possible to generate a set of random numbers and remove duplicates (although at the numbers again cease to be be truly random).

Do you really need a random number or do you need a sequence number or a unique identifier - these are 3 separate things.

> which generate unique key for URL

MySQL and SQLite both support auto-increment column types which will be unique (effectively the same as a sequence number). MySQL even has a mechanism for ensuring uniqueness across equivalent nodes - even where they are not tightly coupled. Oracle provides sequence generators.

Both MySQL and PHP have built-in functionality for generating [uuids](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier), although since most DBMS support surrogate key generation, there is little obvious benefit to this approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a database... Everytime a random number has shown up, put it in a database and next time, compare the random number of the new script with those already in the database.

Answer (score 0):

There are no real "perfect and low price" random number generators!!

The best that can be done from mathematical functions are pseudorandom which in the end seem random enough for most intents and purposes.

`mt_rand` function uses the Mersenne twister, which is a pretty good PRNG!

so it's probably going to be good enough for most casual use.

give a look here for more info: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php

a possible code implementation is

```
<?php
   $random = mt_rand($yourMin, $yourMax);
?>
```

### EDITD:

find a very good explanation here:

[Generate cryptographically secure random numbers in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041509/php-best-random-numbers)

Comment: `$yourMin, $yourMin`? I think you meant `$yourMax` for one of those.

Comment: "There are no real "perfect" random number generators" - yes, there are - but they require some very expensive hardware to measure quantum effects.

Comment: ok... i'll change form "perfect low price" random generator... tnx

Comment: Did you check my edited Q?.. So Still i need to check database is random number existed or not.. I have millions of records its take very long time to check unique number.:(

Answer (score 0):

Use a random number generator, keep stored the already generated values, discard and generate again when you get a duplicate number.

Ignore uniqids and stuff like that because they are just plain wrong.

Comment: Is the whole world gone retarded? Instead of just CHECKING if a number has already been used, you'd prefer generating one that "likely has not?". Instead of doing something that works, you'd prefer something that "likely works"? This is so über-idiotic it leaves me half-speachless half-enraged every time.

Comment: I think people are objecting to this: "Ignore uniqids and stuff like that because they are just plain wrong."  They are not wrong.  They do work.

Comment: @Justin: that was fair, then :)
@ recursive: plain wrong. Read again my previous comment.

Answer (score -1):

The typical answer is to use a GUID or UUID, although I avoid those forms that use only random numbers. (Eg, avoid version 4 GUID or UUIDs)

Comment: Why was this downvoted? (Note that this is exactly what the 'accepted answer' does).