# PHP Random Number Generation Issue

Tags: php, math, random, statistics, probability

```
10,000 Loops
Range 0-1
Base Average: 0.5
Base Standard Deviation: 0.288675134595
=======================================

mt_rand()
Average: 0.337839939116
Standard Deviation: 0.264176807272
---

hexdec(sha1(*GUID*))
Average: 0.37834
Standard Deviation: 0.284251515902 <--
---

mt_rand() based from a SET of defined numbers [01234567899]
Average: 0.496042248107 <--
Standard Deviation: 0.321017564651
---
```

Please could someone help, I cannot seem to find a way to generate RANDOM numbers which complies with a continuous uniform distribution between 0 and 1.

Comment: What kind of output you want to get?

Comment: 10,000 random numbers between 0 and 1 that outputs an average of 0.5 and that have a standard deviation of 0.288675134595 (1/sqrt(12))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [php-best-random-numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041509/php-best-random-numbers) the `mt_rand` is the best out of the box PHP method for it.

The problem however is with your very small subset of random numbers. If you generate random between 0 and 1 you will get a very small deviation. So you could increase the numbers when generating the numbers and then devide them by the top number.

[Check this codepad](http://codepad.org/btWcjHZy) for an average of `0.50015533` and a deviation of `0.29015651152368` on my run.

Keep in mind that if you start rounding the values again to get an actual `0` or `1`, your standard deviation will be around `0.5`.

The code:

```
<?php
$start = 0;
$top = 10000;
$ar = array();
for ($x=1;$x<=10000;$x++) {
  $val = mt_rand($start, $top) / $top;
  $ar[] = $val;
}

$mean = array_sum($ar) / sizeof($ar);

$devs = array();
foreach($ar as $num) {
    $devs[] = pow($num - $mean, 2);
}

$standard_deviation = sqrt(array_sum($devs) / sizeof($devs));

echo 'Max: ' . max($ar);
echo chr(10);
echo 'Min: ' . min($ar);
echo chr(10);
echo 'Average: ' . $mean;
echo chr(10);
echo 'Deviation: ' . $standard_deviation;
?>
```

Comment: No problem. I did see i had a `$start=1`, which should be `$start=0`. Updated now. You could also use a top as `mt_getrandmax()`. And the [manual for mt_getrandmax()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mt-getrandmax.php) also has your random float for best results

Answer (score 1):

If you use ModelFactory in Laravel and obtain this error, this solution can be help:

Change

`$this->faker->randomNumber(100)`

to

`$this->faker->numberBetween(1, 100)`