# PHP generating random numbers

Tags: php

I need to generate about 5,000 random numbers in my script, but the CPU is so fast that I see tendencies in my random numbers.

For example, in the 100 first iterations, I get 80 values between 70 and 99 with rand(0,100);, which can be a REAL inconvenient.

Is there a way to solve such issue, or is randomness not achievable anymore in 2012?

I believe there could be a possibility of generating random numbers from a function executing a random number of times... but I can't figure out one.

Comment: What are you using the random numbers for? Their purpose might lead answers in the right direction

Comment: @Jack I use random numbers to determine a method according to complex probabilities.

Comment: Okay, then `mt_rand()` is "probably" good enough ;-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Better Random Generating PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611/better-random-generating-php)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you using `rand()`? Consider "[generating a better random value](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php)".

Addendum; it's always good to see [two sides](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7808021/whats-the-disadvantage-of-mt-rand) of a coin.

Comment: I am using rand(). mt_rand generates 4x faster, so it should help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`rand` is seeded by time.  `mt_rand` may work better for you.  If you want even better randomness, you can use `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes` (if available) or `/dev/[u]random` if you don't have access to that and are on a system where it is available.  If you use those, you have to convert the bytes with `hexdec(bin2hex())` to get decimal digits, and probably truncate them after that.

Answer (score 0):

mt_rand() is an improvement over rand(). But, random numbers are generated from a sequence, so...

Answer (score 0):

Use this function :

```
function Random($length = 210) {
$characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
$randomString = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
    $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];
}
return $randomString;
}
```

You can change 210 to any number you want hope this helps

Comment: If you're just going to copy/paste and then change function names, at least cite where you copied it from: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4356295/1400370