# Select random entry with probability

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Say I have the following information stored in a database:

```
User         Points
 A            2000
 B            1000
```

I want to select a winner at random with a probability based on the amount of points. In this case, since there's a total of 3000 points, 'A' has a chance of 67% to be selected and 'B' has a 33% chance.

What is the most efficient way to select the winner using PHP (from calculating probabilities to selecting the winner)? Note that the amount of users playing is not fixed and can range up to a large amount (so it should calculate 'each user' rather than fix on A and B).

I've been playing around with potential solutions but have not yet figured it out. I'd love to hear your solution!

Comment: Do you really want to assign those chances or did you mean 67% and 33% ?

Comment: Maybe you could take a look here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611/better-random-generating-php

and here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041509/php-best-random-numbers

:)

Comment: @Michael That's not OP's concern.

Comment: @AmShaeger Whoops, that's a mathematical error on my side :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There could be many similar approaches based on handling the whole map of users and points. That is simple and will work fine if there are not a lot of users. But when the number of users grows there may be a big performance issue regarding memory and even CPU usage. So that I've thought on a possible solution taking performance into account.

Here is described the method I will follow to draw a user depending on probabilities:

```
+------+--------+
| User | Points |     Bar graph:
+------+--------+
|  A   |     20 |     |~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~|
+------+--------+
|  B   |     10 |     |~~~~~~~~~~|
+------+--------+
|  C   |      1 |     |~|
+------+--------+
|  D   |      5 |     |~~~~~|
+------+--------+
|  E   |     12 |     |~~~~~~~~~~~~|
+------+--------+
|  F   |      8 |     |~~~~~~~~|
+------+--------+
 TOTAL |     56 |     Random number: 33
       +--------+

If we take all bars and put them heel and toe we get something like this:
          A               B      C   D        E          F
|~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~|~~~~~~~~~~|~|~~~~~|~~~~~~~~~~~~|~~~~~~~~|
             Position 33 is up here ▲ so we got a winner: user D
```

This is a simple concept but it can ruin performance depending on the algorithm implementation (e.g. if we try to do it sequentially).

What I'll do is to bisect the group of users and compare the sum of points from the first part with the random number. If the number is less than first's part points (accumulated) sum, the number must correspond to a user within that part, and if not, the number corresponds to the second part. This method must to be applied on each chosen part recursively until we get one single user (the winner). This way we throw away 1/2 of the total amount of users on the first iteration, 1/4 on the second one, and so on. This means that if we had 1M users, on second iteration we'd get rid of 750k. Not bad IMO.

Here goes the PHP & MySQL based solution...

User table:

```
CREATE TABLE `User` (
  `id` int(15) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `points` int(15) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Database interaction class:

```
class UserDb
{
    private $pdo;
    private $sumIntervalStmt;

    public function __construct(\PDO $pdo)
    {
        $this->pdo             = $pdo;
        $this->sumIntervalStmt = null;
    }

    public function getTotal()
    {
        $query  = 'SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `User`;';
        $result = $this->pdo->query($query);
        return (int)($result->fetchColumn());
    }

    public function getTotalPoints()
    {
        $query  = 'SELECT SUM(`points`) FROM `User`;';
        $result = $this->pdo->query($query);
        return (int)($result->fetchColumn());
    }

    public function sumPointsInterval($offset, $length)
    {
        if ($this->sumIntervalStmt === null) {
            $this->sumIntervalStmt = $this->pdo->prepare(
                'SELECT SUM(points) FROM (' .
                    'SELECT points FROM `User` LIMIT ?, ?' .
                ') AS Subgroup;'
            );
        }
        $this->sumIntervalStmt->bindValue(1, (int)$offset, \PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $this->sumIntervalStmt->bindValue(2, (int)$length, \PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $this->sumIntervalStmt->execute();
        return (int)($this->sumIntervalStmt->fetchColumn());
    }

    public function getUserByOffset($offset)
    {
        $query = 'SELECT * FROM `User` LIMIT ?, 1;';
        $stmt  = $this->pdo->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bindValue(1, (int)$offset, \PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt->fetchObject();
    }
}
```

User raffle class:

```
class UserRaffle
{
    private $users;

    public function __construct(UserDb $users)
    {
        $this->users = $users;
    }

    public function drawUser()
    {
        $total  = $this->users->getTotal();
        $number = rand(1, $this->users->getTotalPoints());
        $offset = 0;
        $length = ceil($total / 2);
        $count  = $total;
        $sum    = $this->users->sumPointsInterval($offset, $length);
        $accum  = 0;
        while ($count > 1) {
            if ($number <= $sum) {
                $count   -= $count - $length;
                $length   = ceil($length / 2);
                $interval = $this->users->sumPointsInterval($offset, $length);
                $sum      = $accum + $interval;
            } else {
                $accum   += $sum;
                $offset  += $length;
                $count   -= $length;
                $length   = ceil($count / 2);
                $interval = $this->users->sumPointsInterval($offset, $length);
                $sum     += $interval;
            }
        }
        return $this->users->getUserByOffset($offset);
    }
}
```

And the execution:

```
$pdo    = new \PDO('mysql:dbname=test;host=localhost', 'username', '********');
$users  = new UserDb($pdo);
$raffle = new UserRaffle($users);

$winner = $raffle->drawUser();
```

Comment: Wow, this is amazingly well explained and good code! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Just an idea(refering to my comment about chances): Sum all points and order the players. Then choose a random number between 1 and `$sum`. Now you can substract the points of the players from your random number until you hit 0.

```
$players = array(
        "A" => 2000,
        "B" => 1000
);
$sum = array_sum($players);
echo $random = rand(1, $sum)."\n";
foreach($players as $player => $points) {
        $winner = $player;
        $random -= $points;
        if($random <= 0)
                break;
}
echo $winner."\n";
```

You could do this similarly with probabilities `$points/$sum` and a random number between 0.0 and 1.0.

Comment: This works great and I was able to use this with SQL entries by using while() rather than foreach! Thank you!

Comment: What if you got 100k users? Will you run a query returning 100k rows?

Comment: The question says to solve it with PHP. There might be better ways to do so with a MySQL query but this was not asked.

Comment: @AmShaegar Yes, but OP said that users "can range up to a large amount" so this solution doesn't suit well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use formula 1/p on all player. I think it's good idea to normalize it so that the sum of all probabilities is 1. Then you can use a random generator from [0...1] and loop through all players. When the number from the random generator is less then the current player probability then pick this player otherwise substract the current probabilitie from the random number and move to the next player:

```
       x = random([0.0, 1.0])
       for i in 0..n
           if x < probabilities[i]
               choose(i)
              break
           else
              x -= probabilities[i]
          end
        end
```

When you need to normalize you must multiply every 1/px with the reziproken of the sum of all 1/px multiplizieren. For example: you have a vertex with two edges p1=30 and p2=15. 1/(1/30 + 1/15) = 10, also P1 = 10 * 1/30 = 1/3 and P2 = 10 * 1/15 = 2/3.