# SHA512 to generate random numbers in PHP

Tags: php, random, generator, sha

I'm filling an array with random numbers using `$blockhash[$i] = rand().time().rand()`

Then, for each random number in that array I calculate the correspondent SHA512

```
$SecretKey = "60674ccb549f1988439774adb82ff187e63a2dfd403a0dee852e4e4eab75a0b3";
$sha = hash_hmac('sha512', $value, $SecretKey);
```

Split it:

```
$pool  = str_split($sha, 2);
```

Then I get the first number from the $pool array, convert hex to dec and limit it within 1 and 50:

```
$dec = hexdec($pool[0]) % 50 + 1;
```

The problem is that the numbers are not that random and I don't know why. I'm counting the frequency for each number from 1 to 50 but the numbers 1,2,3,4,5 and 6 are coming up often than the others. See graph

[image]

Why is this happening and how to fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get 1-6 more often because you fetch two hexadecimal digits from the hash. That's one byte, so it can store values from `0` to `255`. Then you use modulo `50`. In result you get ranges `0-49`, `50-99`, `100-149`, `150-199`, `200-249` and... `250-255`. This last one is responsible for extra prevalence of 1-6 in your results.

Solution: just use `mt_rand(1,50);`

[edit]

If you really need to convert a number from 0-255 range to 1-50 range, the solution would be scaling and rounding.

```
$number = round(($byteValue)/(255/49))+1;
```

Comment: Yes, I could go the simple way by just doing that but I really need to get the byte from the hash then limit it. So what's the way to limit it to 1-50 without the modulo?

Answer (score 4):

the 2 hex characters you are converting to decimal will be in the range of 0-255. you mod that by 50 and add 1 making 1-6 (range(0-5)+1) occur 6 times over 1-256 while every other number occurs only 5 times. This would account for a ~20% increase in those numbers coming up.

Comment: Thanks! So the problem is the mod. What to do about it? How can I limit it to 1-50 without compromising the randomness?

Answer (score 1):

Neither [`rand()`](http://php.net/rand) or [`mt_rand()`](http://php.net/mt_rand) generate truly random values.

As the manual states:

> This function does not generate cryptographically secure values, and should not be used for cryptographic purposes. If you need a cryptographically secure value, consider using [`openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()`](http://php.net/openssl_random_pseudo_bytes) instead.

See [Better Random Generating PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611/better-random-generating-php) for an StackOverflow question that points the same issue and has some good answers.

Comment: but don't forget I'm using SHA512 to generate some random chars. The random() is just to fill the array with content