# PHP convert SHA to an int for random number generation

Tags: php, string, parsing, random, sha

I'm trying to create fair random numbers in PHP, and I knew how to do it in other languages but I cannot work out how for the life of me in PHP.

I need to take the first 4 bytes/characters of it and turn it into an integer.

Please may someone help me out?

Comment: First 4 bytes, or first 4 characters? which is t?

Comment: Bytes, my bad. Its very late here

Comment: I am studying provably fair numbers, and I can't prove the result when seeding a random. However if I convert a hash to an int I can prove the result.

Comment: The method which I want to use it $int = convert to decimal first 4 bytes.

Comment: maybe this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15794281/sha512-to-generate-random-numbers-in-php?rq=1

Comment: Looks like it could be helpful, thanks